# How to deploy SPFX in 2016?

Tags: 2016, spfx, sharepoint-server

I see one JSON file and two js files inside my deploy folder. I have added inside site assets and given the site assets URL in the CDN path, but I cannot find the app in the "Add an app" page.

I'd appreciate your help.

Comment: I have enabled the security to allow for Json file alone in central admin

Answer (score 3):

Package your solution by command `gulp package-solution`, this will generate the .sppkg file in sharepoint/solution folder, then upload the file to [App Catalog](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/administration/manage-the-app-catalog) site, refer the guideline [here](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/sharepoint/dev/spfx/web-parts/get-started/serve-your-web-part-in-a-sharepoint-page).

If you can't deploy the solution, below thread would be helpful for you.

https://github.com/SharePoint/sp-dev-fx-webparts/issues/331